# Get the list of all users in a particular user group using Ektron API

Tags: c#, ektron

I have a C# web application which uses Ektron CMS (I am using Ektron 8.5). Can I get the list of all users in a particular user group using Ektron API?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got answer. Its given as follows..

```
List<UserData> userData = new List<UserData>();
Ektron.Cms.API.User.User user = new Ektron.Cms.API.User.User();
long groupId = Id; //your group id
foreach (UserData u in user.GetUsers(groupId, "username")) //group id + sort by field
{
    userData.Add(user.GetUser(u.Id));
}
return userData;
```